# How do i check if object is a div or a li?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jquery or JS how do i check if an object is a div or a li?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
jQuery(someElement).is('li'); // => return true if it's an <li>
jQuery(someElement).is('div'); // => returns true if it's a <div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Check it's [tagName](http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/prop_element_tagname.asp) property.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quick example:

```
$("div, li").click(function() {
    alert(this.nodeName);
});
```

There are some differences (mainly IE, surprised?) between [`tagName` and `nodeName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-822762427).   [The few that matter can be found here](http://aleembawany.com/2009/02/11/tagname-vs-nodename/).

Comment: @Ian - Undelete! Your's is a perfectly valid answer, just posting this so people know of some odd cases between the two as well :)

Comment: done. I just hate to think of someone using something which didn't work across browsers. jQuery FTW!

Answer (score 2):

use the `tagName` property

Answer (score 0):

How about this function in pure JS, you can pass the element to it and it will return the tag for you:

```
function whichTag(el) {
  return el && el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase();
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
whichTag(document.getElementById('link')); //return 'a'
whichTag(document.getElementById('list')); //return 'li'
whichTag(document.getElementById('side')); //return 'div'
```

If you want to use jQuery, just simply use is(); like below:

```
$('#link').is('a'); //return true
$('#list').is('li'); //return true
$('#side').is('div'); //return true
```

These IDs are just as an example, make sure they exist in your document, otherwise all of them will return `null`.